# How to display PDF in Nativescript-vue Webview component

Tags: javascript, html, nativescript, nativescript-vue

How to display local PDF in Nativescript-vue Webview component?

```html
my nativescript-vue element:

<WebView src="~/html/web.html" />

web.html:

<iframe src="mases.pdf" width="100%" height="100%">
This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: Download PDF
</iframe>
```

always return blank page

Comment: Did you try using the nativescript-pdf-view plugin (https://github.com/madmas/nativescript-pdf-view)?

Comment: Unlike iOS, WebView on Android is not capable of displaying PDF. Go with plugin.